# Selenium: Counting Total <th> Using XPATH in Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, row

I am trying to count the total  using the xpath. The xpath is very long and it goes like this:

```
String path = "/html/body/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/div/table[4]/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/th";
```

This is my code:

```
List <WebElement> pagination= driver.findElements(By.xpath(path));
page_size = pagination.size();
```

The result of this is incorrect. I'm expecting 37 because there are 37 th's but it's only giving 31. Any idea what's wrong with my code? Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to count the total th in the document or inside the particular table?

Comment: The th in the particular table

Comment: Can you share your HTML.I think you have to modify your path. This path can be simplified to a shorter path.

Comment: Long XPaths like that are brittle... they are very susceptible to any small change in the HTML between the `html` tag and the tag you are looking for. It's much better to handcraft a CSS selector or XPath to find the element you are looking for more directly. You will need to post a link to the page or the relevant HTML for us to help you do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your XPath is correct. You can do it in Chrome developer tools, that is opened by F12. Click RMB on the element you want to find and select Inspect element. There you'll see the Elements tab opened with your element highlighted. Click RMB on it, then Copy > Copy XPATH. 
You can test this XPATH in search window in chrome's DevTools or (as I prefer) in [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firepath/) for Firefox. If you make it less specific, it will show you all the elements, that are suitable for your XPATH.

Answer (score 0):

You can try fetching parent table element with some other selector like css selector,id,name or whatever is unique for that table.

Once you have that element you can use

```
driver.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
```

This should return you all the 'th's from required table.

It will be very helpful if you could share the html page source of the page.